# Rename uploaded images using MULTER

Tags: node.js, image-uploading, multer

I am uploading the images using multer. They all are given random names (dec93b9f333c7a731723b06ce73c0bbc.jpg), which is very bad for SEO... Can you guys help me out, how to save the images with the pattern: 'fixed-name'+'random-name'.extension. Then at least part of the file would be readable for the google. Thanks!

```
app.set('images', '/var/www/images');
app.use(app.get('images'), express.static(app.get('images')));
var multerForImage = multer({
    dest: app.get('images'),
    onParseStart: function (file) {
        console.log("Started parsing file stream", file);
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        console.log('File recieved: ', file.originalname);
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file, req, res) {
        console.log("File upload complete");
        var path = app.get('images') + "/" + file.name;
        var user = req.session.user;
        res.json({
            success: true,
            data: path
        });

    },
    onFileUploadData: function (file, data, req, res) {
        console.log('Data recieved for file upload');
    },
    onParseEnd: function (req, next) {
        console.log("Parsing data end for file upload");
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the storage configuration.

```
app.set('images', '/var/www/images');
app.use(app.get('images'), express.static(app.get('images')));
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, app.get('images'))
        },

        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            const randomPart = uuidV4(); // use whatever random you want.
            const extension = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
            cb(null, 'fixed-name'+ randomPart + `.${extension}`)

        }
    })

    var multerForImage = multer({
        storage: storage,
        ...
```